# Cascaded HTML Tables for Reports

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Cascaded HTML Tables for Reports:

I want to show the List of Customers with their respective products in the below format somewhat like :

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/MultiNestMDGridview/MultiNestMDGridview.jpg

One Customers can have multiple products so want to show Multiple Rows within that single Customer Detail Row as in above example.

I am using ASPxGridView of Devexpress and DO NOT want to use Crystal Reports and Master Detail Grid to acheive above.

So Please tell me some ways to acheive above result using GridView OR using HTML Tables converted from Datatables passed.

Please Help. I m stuck.

Comment: These should help : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198345/how-do-i-create-a-pivot-table-layout-in-javascript-html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774531/javascript-pivot-table

Comment: @Ravi.. I want some standard Way. As a workaround, I can make an HTML Table and cascade another table with that But I am looking for a standard way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used **DevExpress XtraReports** to solve the issue.. !! Tried Master Detail Grid Examples but Xtra Reports had what I needed to acheive..